# Firebase Handle Async Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that goes as follows:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/users/{id}/').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

//do some processing here

var number;
snapshot.after.ref.parent.once('value').then((newSnapshot) => {
    number = newSnapshot.child('number').val();
});
console.log(number);

//do some processing with the use of var number

//returning the updates after processing
return snapshot.after.ref.update(updates);
});
```

I realized that the variable number is coming out to be undefined as the function that I am using to obtain the value of number is running asynchronously. However, I am unable to think of a method to convert this implementation so that it works the way I want it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain a new .then() to perform the processing on this number. For example:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/users/{id}/').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

...
var number;
return snapshot.after.ref.parent.once('value').then((newSnapshot) => {
        number = newSnapshot.child('number').val();
    }).then((number) => {
        console.log(number);
        //do some processing with the use of var number
        snapshot.after.ref.update(updates);
    });
});
```

Comment: It should work just like this, or am I wrong ? :
`snapshot.after.ref.parent.once('value').then(newSnapshot => {
    number = newSnapshot.child('number').val();
    console.log(number);
    //do some processing with the use of var number
});`

Comment: How do I handle the last return statement in these cases? The updates that are returned are dependent on the processing done with var number.

Comment: You can return the whole chain. See my updated answer.